# RxJava Operator that takes a sample out of multiple events in a certain time frame

Tags: android, rx-java

Is there an operator that takes 1 event out of N consecutive equal events in a certain time frame ?
Example: I have an Rx event bus and i have multiple sources that sometimes send the same event at the same, So instead of processing each event, i just want to process one of them and neglect the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably not the optimal way of doing this, but one way comes to my mind. You can cut your stream into time ***windows*** in which you will get rid of duplicates and forward them to flatMap .

```
stream()
    .window(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .flatMap(window -> window.distinct()) // you can alter the way you handle duplicates
    .subscribe()
```

To brush things up, you can wrap those two operators into a custom one and apply it through `compose`